# Can I use an interjection like "by God" to imply I'm talking about God later in the sentence?

Tags: interjections

Can I use the phrase "by God" to imply I'm talking about God, while also using it as an interjection?

So e.g.:

- By God, it was a difficult thing to do, who has long since given up on me.

Comment: You might possibly get away with it in a written piece if you moved the relative clause up: By God (who has long since given up on me) it was a difficult thing to do!

Comment: @TimRomano appreciated. specifically (sorry i never provide the right context) i'm asking whether the quote *could* be of god, in this poem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banal_Sojourn

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. Are you referring to **Pardie**?

Comment: not just that word, no. i'm asking if "Pardie... [other stuff] who [that is, god] tells me..." makes sense

Comment: *Pardie! summer is like a fat beast, sleepy in mildew, / Our old bane, green and bloated, serene, who cries,/ 'That bliss of stars, that princox of evening heaven!'*.   The antecedent of "who" in "who cries" is not "Pardie".

Comment: categorically, ofc is what i mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35071/discussion-between-user3293056-and-tim-romano).

Comment: The Third Commandment is still in effect, you know.

Comment: Nope.  You might argue that it's technically correct, but most people would read it as nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not grammatical. To understand why, replace "God" with "John" and simplify the sentence, because perhaps the "By God" idiom doesn't allow you to see it very clearly.

```
*By John, cutting the grass was a difficult thing to do, who has long since given up on me
```

Comment: hello digicula. thanks for the reply, tho tbh i'm not sure i follow

Comment: In the sentence I gave you, `*By John, cutting the grass was a difficult thing to do, who has long since given up on me`, the syntax is improper. "By John" here simply describes the phrase "cutting the grass was a difficult thing to do" (and rather poorly; "According to John" would be more idiomatic). For the sentence to be grammatical, you would need to phrase it as such: "John, who has long since given up on me, says that cutting the grass was a difficult thing to do".

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, tho i'd have to just agree rather than think it thru. grammar eh

Comment: what about "I swore to John, cutting the grass is a pain, who has long since stopped paying me attention"

Comment: This is barely better, but it doesn't work without swapping the clauses: It should read: `I swore to John, who has long since stopped paying me attention, that cutting the grass is a pain`. It's not elegant, and I wouldn't use it, but it's grammatical